# How to display \r\n as new line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I browsing a log file in notepad++. The file has \r\n wherever a new line should start, but notepad just displays the \r\n characters:

```
[Header]\r\n2011-04-23 13:14:53,867 [1] DEBUG Themis.Program Enter application
2011-04-23 13:14:57,505 [1] DEBUG Themis.Program Exit application
[Footer]\r\n[Header]\r\n2011-04-23 13:23:15,690 [1] DEBUG Themis.Program Enter application
```

I'd like it to display it like this:

```
[Header]
2011-04-23 13:14:53,867 [1] DEBUG Themis.Program Enter application
2011-04-23 13:14:57,505 [1] DEBUG Themis.Program Exit application
[Footer]
[Header]
2011-04-23 13:23:15,690 [1] DEBUG Themis.Program Enter application
```

Is it possible to do this. Is there maybe another app that can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace regexp `\\r\\n` with `\n`.

Comment: This works, but I don't want to do any replacements. Since I can control the log file contents, what should I log instead of \r\n to get notepad to recognize as 'new line'?

Comment: @Yoav: Make your program write *real* newline characters instead.

Comment: \r\n is 0x0D and 0x0A, or 0x0D0A. In Unicode, this is CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A). Depending on your programming language, the existence of the backslashes and characters "\r\n" may indicate that you have some option set incorrectly. For example, in Python, if you have your string marked as "raw," it won't respect your newline code.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in 2 steps

Press <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd> to open Replace window

1) First make sure that the Search Mode is in Normal mode. Then replace \r\n with some meaningless random word such as: abcdefg (which you're sure that is not within your text)

2) Then change the Search mode to **Extended** or **Regular expression** mode and replace this word with \n

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you.